# How can I get waitFor to work when using canopy?

Tags: f#, canopy-web-testing

I'm using canopy, and I can't get the `waitFor` method to work.

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
waitFor noBlockUI
```

where the noBlockUI function is:

```
let noBlockUI () =
    (someElement "div.blockUI").IsNone
```

Now the waitFor call is in a function in an F# module, and I'm calling that function from a C# project.

I've found that I have to add FSharp.Core to my C# project to get any of the calls to work.  There are a couple of Microsoft-authored NuGet packages for FSharp:

- [FSharp.Core 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/)
- [FSharp.Core for F# 3.0 (versions 2.3.0.0, 4.3.0.0)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core.3/)

If I use the 4.0.0 package, then when execution hits method with the waitFor, I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 canopy.core.someElement(System.String)'.

But if I use the 4.3.0.0 package, then immediately when I try to run my tests, I get this:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for '.$canopy.core' threw an exception.
>     ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any ideas what I can to do get `waitFor` to work?

Comment: For the time being I went back to the C# code I originally wrote to wait for the condition above.  Still hoping to find an F# solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an app.config file containing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  I took a look in the app.config of my C# project, but it already has that section in there, whether I use the 4.0.0 or the 2.3.0/4.3.0 NuGet package.